# Processing error while using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, runtime-error

I'm using python and selenium to scrape [Tradingview](https://in.tradingview.com/chart)

While my app was running I got this error:
[image]

I have never got this error before. I don't know why I'm getting it and how I can fix it.

I don't know if this is a big issue or not.

Can someone tell me whether I should be concerned about this. If so, can you also tell me how I can fix it?